# Highchart with dynamic data

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to generate chart when a user click on link so the data.php get data from db based on user request and redirect user to chart.php to generate the chart while user is redirected the chart is totally blink.

Data.php file code bellow

```
<?php

include('../../conn.php');

@$query = $connection->query("SELECT * from localitems where city='".$_REQUEST['prov']."' ");

$category = array();
$category['name'] = 'Month';

$series1 = array();
$series1['name'] = 'Wheat';
$series2 = array();
$series2['name'] = 'Rice';

$series3 = array();
$series3['name'] = 'Maize';
$series4 = array();
$series4['name'] = 'Mungbeans';

$series5 = array();
$series5['name'] = 'Pea';
$series6 = array();
$series6['name'] = 'Potato';
$series7 = array();
$series7['name'] = 'Milk';
$series8 = array();
$series8['name'] = 'Beef ';
$series9 = array();
$series9['name'] = 'Mutton';
$series10 = array();
$series10['name'] = 'Chicken';
$series11 = array();
$series11['name'] = 'DAP ';
$series12 = array();
$series12['name'] = 'Agriculture';
$series13 = array();
$series13['name'] = 'Pair of Oxan';
$series14 = array();
$series14['name'] = 'Water Pump';
$series15 = array();
$series15['name'] = 'Tractor Hiring';

while($r =$query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $category['data'][] =$r['month'];
    $series1['data'][] = $r['Wheat'];
    $series2['data'][] = $r['Rice'];
    $series3['data'][] = $r['Maize'];
    $series4['data'][] = $r['Mungbeans'];
    $series5['data'][] = $r['Pea'];
    $series6['data'][] = $r['Potato'];
    $series7['data'][] = $r['Milk'];
    $series8['data'][] = $r['Beef'];
    $series9['data'][] = $r['Mutton'];
    $series10['data'][] = $r['Chicken'];
    $series11['data'][] = $r['Dap'];
    $series12['data'][] = $r['Oxan_pair'];
    $series13['data'][] = $r['Agriculture'];
    $series14['data'][] = $r['Waterpump'];
    $series15['data'][] = $r['Tractor_hiring'];
}
    $result = array();
    array_push($result,$category);
    array_push($result,$series1);
    array_push($result,$series2);
    array_push($result,$series3);
    array_push($result,$series4);
    array_push($result,$series5);
    array_push($result,$series6);
    array_push($result,$series7);
    array_push($result,$series8);
    array_push($result,$series9);
    array_push($result,$series10);
    array_push($result,$series11);
    array_push($result,$series12);
    array_push($result,$series13);
    array_push($result,$series14);
    array_push($result,$series15);
    print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    if($result==true){
    header('location:chart.php');
   }else{ echo "Nothing fetched";}

//mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This file reads data.php and generate.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Imported Kabul</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Local Item Price in Kabul',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Price Per (KG, Hour, Labor)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'Vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }
            $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                options.series[2] = json[3];
                options.series[3] = json[4];
                options.series[4] = json[5];
                options.series[5] = json[6];
                options.series[6] = json[7];
                options.series[7] = json[8];
                options.series[8] = json[9];
                options.series[9] = json[10];
                options.series[10] = json[11];
                options.series[11] = json[12];
                options.series[12] = json[13];
                options.series[13] = json[14];
                options.series[14] = json[15];

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
        </script>

        <script src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/exporting.js"></script>
<style>
.text{
    font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:medium;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the JSON you are using for `options` invalid? Might want to run that past a validator.

Comment: sorry i am newbie. What do you refer?

Comment: I'd suggest you try and get the chat working without using any `PHP` first, just using example data ... perhaps using something like http://jsfiddle.net/

Also you *really* shouldn't do your SQL query like that: look into SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console log ? (F12).

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    drawchart();
    //dynamic value to function u can feed here
});

function drawchart ()
{
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({    

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        tooltip: {
            shared: false,
            useHTML: true,
            footerFormat: '</table> <span>"new text"</span>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },

        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y} EUR</b></td></tr>'
                }
            }
        },


        series: [{
            name: 'Short',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            name: 'Long named series',
            data: [129.9, 171.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 195.6, 154.4].reverse()
        }]

    });
}
```